# what are controls .NET equivalent to this image?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

in this picture,I can see: `MenuStrip`,??,`TextBox`

[image]

how do I an bar like this that have the enumeration?
I hope this clear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which bar? What enumeration? Where's the control between the menu strip and the text editing component - I can't see anything between them.

Comment: Are you asking about the line numbers? They are part of the text edit control - try http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/

Comment: ListView with View = Details, HeaderStyle = None.

Comment: I see a title bar, which is an integral part of the form, a MenuStrip and some kind of (non-standard) editing control. To say it frankly, it is not clear!

Comment: Jack, could you post another image with a (red, freehand) circle around the element you're talking about?  (Also, come on guys, this is a very vague question, but it's not a *-8* question...)

Comment: C'mon guys, he's asking about the line numbers, what's wrong with that? +1 from me

Comment: @Inerdial What do you mean "What enumeration?"? He's talking about the 1 followed by the 2 in the gray bar.

Comment: @M3NTA7, I didn't also understand the question more than Inerdial. Good for you that you can guess the questions. Could you explain it for us what he is really after?

Comment: I may be wrong and it is up to the OP to explain. From what I see and read, It appears that what he is looking for is to determine what control is used in his example image that he should use to get the same type of display of numbers next to the text.

Comment: @M3NTA7,`I may be wrong`, This is the point. People just try to **guess** what the real question could be.

Comment: The question was clear to me. I said I 'may' be wrong, but I don't think so.

Comment: @M3NTA7: Yes, that much is clear. The issue is *which* control he's referring to. And in general, questions that are unclear enough so as to require/promote guessing in the answers are good candidates for closing. If you understand a question and think that you can improve it, *please* feel free to use the "edit" link and suggest an edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're talking about the menu bar at the top of the window (just below the caption/title bar, which you should get for free from any `Form` object), then that is *not* a `MenuStrip` control.

The `MenuStrip` control doesn't use the native Windows menu bar, which means it's going to look very different on Windows Vista and later where the appearance of the standard menu bar was altered to be blue and plasticky. Since `MenuStrip` is drawn entirely in C# code, it's going to look permanently cheesy and stick out like a sore thumb.

If you want the standard Windows menu bar, you need to use the old [`MainMenu` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mainmenu.aspx). This is what *everyone* used back in the early days of .NET, but it's still available for backwards-compatibility and for people who care about what their apps look like. You'll probably have to add it to the toolbox manually because it's not there by default. Right-click on your toolbox and click "Choose Items", then find `MainMenu` in the list of available controls and ensure that it is checked.

As Blorgbeard suggested in the comments, if you're talking about the line numbers and the text editing control, they're not the standard `TextBox` control, either. In fact, they're not a standard Windows control at all. That's a custom control designed specifically for editing code, probably [Scintilla](http://scintilla.org/).
You can find a .NET implementation here: http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/

Comment: It is scintilla, used in this [DCode Editor](http://www.dprogramming.com/dcode.php)